# Remove lines from file which have 4 or more of the same character in a series

Tags: linux, bash, text, automation

I hope the title is sufficient in explaining what I need help with, but I'll explain it in more detail.

I have a text file which contains 7 character long strings on each line. The strings look like this:

```
aaaaaad
aaabbbd
AAaa123
AkLmbB3
```

This file has a few hundred thousand of these 7 character long strings and I need to remove any line which contains too many of the same character that is in sequence. For example:

```
aaaaLu1 <-- Remove this, because there is 4 `a` characters next to each other.

aaBaa1b <-- Keep this line

bbbb1Lk <-- Remove this line, because there is 4 `b` characters next to each other.

bababab <-- Keep this line, as the `b` characters aren't next to each other, even though there is 4 of them.
```

Is there a way of doing this from the GNU+Linux command line? Maybe a regular expression using grep or sed? I've looked around the internet for grep regular expressions but they typically only check for how many of the same character are in a line, not if they are in sequence of each other. If there is anything more effective than using a regular expression (which can be automated and ran from a Linux-based distro), I am open to such suggestions.

I am currently using Manjaro Linux.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please include your attempt to solve this, in the programming language of your choice, then update the tags to include the programming language? As it stands, it looks like you are fishing for a basic regexp, but it may be that there's a better way to handle this if we get the context in which you are encountering the problem.

Comment: I've looked around the internet for grep regular expressions but they typically only check for how many of the same character are in a line, not if they are in sequence of each other. I shall update the post. FYI anything that can be ran from the Linux command line, but currently I believe a regular expression will be the most... Likelihood way of getting around my problem.

Comment: `grep` is just a command. Its name is an acronym for "Global Regular Expression Print", which is also the notation of the ed/ex/vi command which `grep` is based on. The thing that you may be looking for is called a "back reference", and depending on your platform (since the `grep` command is not actually part of bash), it may or may not support them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu sed` you may use this command:

```
sed -E '/([[:alnum:]])\1{3}/d' file
```

```
aaBaa1b
bababab
```

where `file` is:

```
cat file
```

```
aaaaLu1
aaBaa1b
bbbb1Lk
bababab
```

To save changes inline into same file, use:

```
sed -i -E '/([[:alnum:]])\1{3}/d' file
```

**Details:**

- `([[:alnum:]])`: Match any alpha-numeric and capture it in 1st capture group
- `\1{3}`: `\1` is back-reference of first capture group and `{3}` matches 3 occurrences of same
- `/d`: Delete these lines

Comment: Thank you! I'll upvote this once the command has finished running, and if it has worked properly. Currently the file I am sorting is over 1GB in size, so it's gonna take a while.

Answer (score 1):

Take any char `(.)`, backrefence it `\1`, and see if that appears three more times `{3}`. For instance, using `ag`, which employs perl regex:

```
ag -sv '(.)\1{3}'
```